# Is using malloc to allocate a buffer faster than using a statically allocated buffer when making large buffers?

Tags: c, performance, memory

I am trying to make an array like this:

```c
char tmp[4][32768];
//code
```

This is in a function and I discovered that making this array global will increase the speed of the program (unfortunately I could not keep it like that as the function calls itself recursively when encountering certain data). I would like to make this function faster but I have read that `malloc` can be pretty slow. So would it be faster to leave it like that or do this?:

```c
char** tmp;
tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
tmp[0] = malloc(32768);
tmp[1] = malloc(32768);
tmp[2] = malloc(32768);
tmp[3] = malloc(32768);
//code
free(tmp[0]);
free(tmp[1]);
free(tmp[2]);
free(tmp[3]);
free(tmp);
```

Comment: Undecidable. You need to benchmark

Comment: `tmp = malloc(4);` does not allocate enough. You need to do `tmp = malloc(4 * sizeof (char *));`

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 thanks i forgot about that lol (i updated the post)

Comment: If you are in a critical code and your function is not recursive, you can preallocate a big thread-local buffer in the heap to mitigate the cost of doing mallocs (but do not forget to free it).

Comment: Is there a limit to your recursion? Then there is an easy way out with the stack allocation. If not - you can manage those arrays globally by allocating new ones as needed, and only free it once, on exit. The max number of allocation will be a number of your recursions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a matter of being faster or slower.  It's a matter of whether or not you blow up the stack.

You're creating an array 128K in size which is fairly large for a local variable, and locals typically live on the stack.  If you call this function recursively, that's another 128K on the stack for each call.  Just a few recursive calls would be enough to cause a stack overflow which would likely result in a crash.

Allocating memory dynamically is pretty much your only option.  You can however reduce this to a single allocation:

```
char (*tmp)[32768] = malloc(4 * sizeof *tmp);
```

This allocation works because a 2D array of type `char [4][32768]` decays to a pointer of type `char (*)[32768]` which matches the type of `tmp` above.  The memory returned by `malloc` is enough for 4 objects of type `char[32768]`.  This memory is contiguous, unlike doing 4 separate calls to `malloc` for each subarray.

Comment: Since `sizeof (char)` is guaranteed to be 1, I believe `malloc(4 * 32768)` is equivalent to `malloc(4 * sizeof (char [32768])`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Did one better, using the dereferenced variable instead of the type.

Comment: Was going to make an answer that there is a cost to malloc, but honestly I think that just muddies the waters and leads back to "it's not slow until you measure it and know it is slow with actual data."  I like your answer much better.

Comment: Now there's only one problem, the function is 194 lines long and contains 31 returns. Search and replace to the rescue! (thanks btw)

Comment: @PQCraft That sounds like a great use case for `goto`.

Comment: @dbush -  I don't understand this answer (which means many people will not as well) - can you explain how that malloc is being assigned to the various entries in the array of pointers in tmp as part of this answer?

Comment: @dbush Ah good idea, I will try that (it's mostly `return 0`)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I actually ended up doing it this way: `char* tmp[4] = {malloc(32768), malloc(32768), malloc(32768), malloc(32768)};`

Comment: @PQCraft That will make your array disjoint which could potentially affect the speed of accessing it.  The method in the answer uses a single contiguous block of memory just as a 2D array would.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan it's not an array of pointers, it's a pointer to an array of 32768 `char`s, made possible thanks to the `()`s and operator precedence. Hopefully that clears things up (just noticed the answer edit, that explains it better).

Comment: Much clearer now - thank you!  Headed over to godbolt to read the assembler and that firmed it up in my mind as well.

Comment: Fun fact - I compiled this as C++ and it doesn't like it: `error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char (*)[32768]' with an rvalue of type 'void *'`

Comment: @MichaelDorgan C++ doesn't allow an implicit cast to/from `void *`.  You need to add a cast.

Comment: I am surprised the standard allow the right-hand-side expression of an initialization statement to access the information about the type defined in this same statement. I though it was forbidden or would results in an UB...

Comment: @JérômeRichard The operand of `sizeof` is not evaluated unless it is a VLA.  It is just observed for its type and is computed at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

All things being equal, allocating memory through `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`) will be both slower and more labor-intensive to manage than using an `auto` (local) array, which will be slower than using a `static` array.

All things are typically not equal, though.  As you've discovered, a `static` array doesn't work well when dealing with recursion (or when you just need to preserve multiple states, as anyone who's tried to use `strtok` to tokenize a string like `"a=b&c=d&e=f"` knows all too well).  A 128K `auto` array is somewhat on the large side, and if the function is recursive that can be an issue since stack space is typically limited for an individual process.

This is kind of an ideal use case for dynamic memory, which typically isn't as limited as memory on the stack.  The trade-off is that it will be slower that the alternatives and will require more work on your part.

Exactly how much slower will depend on how you allocate and use it - allocating it as a single contiguous chunk like so only requires a single `malloc` (and corresponding `free`) call and should be better for locality:

```
char (*tmp)[32768] = malloc( 4 * sizeof *tmp );
if ( tmp )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    strcpy( tmp[i], some_string ); // or however you intend to use tmp;
  ...
  free( tmp );
}
```

but if your heap is sufficiently fragmented you may not be able to allocate it as a single contiguous chunk and have to do it piecemeal, using multiple `malloc` (and `free`) calls:

```
char **tmp = malloc( 4 * sizeof *tmp );
if ( tmp )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
  {
    tmp[i] = malloc( sizeof *tmp[i] * 32768 );
    if ( tmp[i] )
    {
      strcpy( tmp[i], some_string );
    }
  }
  ...
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    free( tmp[i] );
  free( tmp );
}
```

The only way to know for sure which is faster and works better for your purposes is to code up multiple versions and to *measure* their performance.

Having said all that...

It doesn't matter how fast your code is if it does the wrong thing, or gives the wrong answer, or vomits all over the floor at the first hint of bad input, or exposes sensitive data, or provides an entry point for malware, or cannot be modified or maintained.  Code for correctness and maintainability *first*, without consideration for raw execution speed, then for all the other issues listed above.  Unless you have a *hard* performance requirement ("This operation must complete within X msec"), don't worry about speed.  Get it right first, then if you aren't satisfied you can always tune the performance later.

Also, depending on what the rest of your code does, the deltas between the different methods of allocating and managing that memory may be insignificant - if your code is spending the bulk of its time waiting for someone to type in data, then the extra few clocks spent using `malloc` as opposed to an `auto` array really don't matter.  On the other hand, if you're calling this code thousands of times in a tight loop, those extra clocks will add up to a significant difference.

Make your decisions based on *analysis* and *measurement*, not guesswork.